Excel/VBA: copying a range without changing types
I am trying to copy a Range from one worksheet to another worksheet. The source workbook and worksheet are in different workbooks, with the macro running in the target workbook. I open the source workbook in a separate Excel application object that is not visible. The range is about 1,000 lines with 15 columns. In the source data there are some cells with numbers stored as text and I need to preserve them as text.
When I just assign Value or Value2, unfortunately the text cells with number in them get converted to numbers. This is the code I tried:
targetRange.Value = sourceRange.Value

or
targetRange.Value2 = sourceRange.Value2

Using Copy does not work, first I get message box saying that Excel is waiting for another OLE application, and then after a long time says the Copy command has failed. This is the code I used:
sourceRange.Copy targetRange

What copy method could work in this scenario? From two workbooks in two Excel applications, preserving numbers stored as text as such.

This is an example of resolving the issue.
Sub anotherwb()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb2 = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\users\username\desktop\wb1.xlsm")
wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10").Copy 
wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("A100").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wb2.Close
Set app = Nothing
End Sub

Take care that empty cells at the end of the range are not included in the copied range. If you define in wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("A100").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues the complete range like A100:A109 and the last cell is empty in the source range a warning message will be pop up.

Why do you open a second Excel instance for that?

Because this is the spec. of the asker

Ah, I see, missed that. Seems unnecessary to me.

Thank you, this works. Not sure why the direct copy fails but the copy via clipboard works, but who am I to question why ...
About the two instances, my only reason was that I wanted to open the second workbook in the background, not visible to the user. It seems that is only doable via a separate Excel instance, at least I did not find a way to invisibly open a workbook in a visible Excel instance.
What I added to my code is app.CutCopyMode = False after the paste, this clears the clipboard and avoids the popup asking if the clipboard content shall be kept when closing the app.

I think you just need to set the target cells format to "text", prior to copy.
I don't remember exact deails on how to do that, but you could use "Macro Recorder" feature of Excel so it will give you example. Just google up something like "Excel Automate tasks with the Macro Recorder". That's an extremely handy feature if you know what you can do something within Excel but don't know how to do it in VBA.

Use destRange.NumberFormat = "@"
